# Vala: determine generic type inside List at runtime

Tags: generics, reflection, vala

I am new to Vala and playing around a bit. Currently I am looking for a way to determine the type parameter of a generic list at runtime.

The code below uses 'reflection' to print the properties of the Locations class. However, I am not able to determine at runtime that this list contains instances of string.

Is there a way to do this? Or is this not supported in Vala?

```
using Gee;
class Locations : Object {
    public string numFound { get; set; }
    public ArrayList<string> docs { get; set; }
}

void main () {
    ObjectClass ocl = (ObjectClass) typeof (Locations).class_ref ();
    ParamSpec[] properties = ocl.list_properties ();
    foreach (ParamSpec spec in properties) {
        string fieldName = spec.get_nick ();
        stdout.printf (" fieldName: %s\n", fieldName);
        Type fieldType = spec.value_type;
        stdout.printf (" Type : %s\n", fieldType.name());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fieldName: numFound
Type : gchararray
fieldName: docs
Type : GeeArrayList
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a generic way to do this since GObject/GType simply isn't that expressive.  For example, if you were using a `GLib.GenericArray` (or a `GLib.List`) instead of a `Gee.ArrayList` you would be out of luck.

That said, libgee does provide a way.  Like most containers in libgee, `Gee.ArrayList` implements [`Gee.Traversable`](http://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.Traversable.html), which includes the [`element_type`](http://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.Traversable.element_type.html) property.  Note, however, that you need an instance, not just the `GLib.ObjectClass`.

Comment: Great! Your answer helped me a lot. Tonight  I'll post a functioning example.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the suggestion of the first answer, I have come up with this solution.
This is exactly what I was looking for:

```
using Gee;
class Locations : Object {
    public int numFound { get; set; }
    public Gee.List<string> docs { get; set; }
    public Locations () {
        docs = new ArrayList<string>();
    }
}

void main () {
    ObjectClass ocl = (ObjectClass) typeof (Locations).class_ref ();
    ParamSpec[] properties = ocl.list_properties ();
    Locations locs = new Locations();
    foreach (ParamSpec spec in properties) {
        string fieldName = spec.get_nick ();
        Type fieldType = spec.value_type;

        // get the docs instance from the locations instance
        GLib.Value props = Value( fieldType);
        locs.get_property(fieldName, ref props);
        stdout.printf ("Field type %s : %s\n", fieldName, props.type_name());
        if(props.holds(typeof (Gee.Iterable))) {
            Gee.Iterable docs =  (Gee.Iterable)props.get_object();
            stdout.printf ("\tList parameter type : %s\n", docs.element_type.name());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Field type numFound : gint
Field type docs : GeeList
    List parameter type : gchararray
```