# Accessing pointer object properties in Vala

Tags: pointers, vala

I have refactored a bit my code, so i need a pointer that could contain multiple liste types :

```
owl_list = new Gee.LinkedList<OpenWithAction> ();
a_list = new Gee.LinkedList<OpenAppAction> ();

Gee.List* any_list = null;
```

So i have a pointer any_list which i can use to access either owl_list or a_list (depending on a switch no present here, but assume there is)

```
if (!any_list.size)
    return null;
```

But this will fail as valac throws at me `` error: The name `size' does not exist in the context of `Gee.List*'
      if (!any_list.size) ``

I haven't done any C,C++ since a very long time and I'm no vala expert, since i use more typeless languages, but is there any way this could work ?

**EDIT:**

I just tried

```
fieldType = OpenWithAction.get_type();
if (!(any_list as Gee.List<fieldType>).size)
```

`` error: The type name `fieldType' could not be found
      if (!(any_list as Gee.List<fieldType>).size) ``
Obviously I'm doing something wrong, what i'm trying to do is : [Vala: determine generic type inside List at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710328/vala-determine-generic-type-inside-list-at-runtime), i just can"t manage to implement it.
            return null;

**EDIT 2:**

I just solved partially my problem :

As said by @jens-mühlenhoff, yes **OpenWithAction** and **OpenAppAction** have a common ancestor and it is **GLib.Action**

So all i had to do is declare :

```
Gee.List<Action> any_list = null;
```

instead of

```
Gee.List* any_list = null;
```

now `foreach (var action in any_list)` is working, but i'm still getting an error with

```
if (any_list->size == null)
    return null;
```

`` error: The name `size' does not exist in the context of `Gee.List<Synapse.Action>?'
      if (any_list->size == null) ``

another try is :

```
if (!any_list.size)
    return null;
```

`` Operator not supported for `int'
      if (!any_list.size) ``

Comment: Do OpenWithAction and OpenAppAction have a common supertype?

Comment: I am surprised that this compiles at all (as is), because `Gee.List<G>` is a generic type.

Comment: I just found what i'm trying to do :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710328/vala-determine-generic-type-inside-list-at-runtime
But i'm still having difficulties to actually implement it.
Also it does not compile

Comment: Yes they do have a common type, and using it solved my problem, partially : i can now make iterations with foreach, but still can't access size prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things i was doing wrong :

**1-**
Like in C# **i should not have used a pointer if not needed**. So using :
`Gee.List<Action> any_list = null;` is just working fine. The explanation is that **OpenWithAction** and **OpenAppAction** have a common ancestor class, So declaring a List with that type is just working fine ( on the other hand i don't know in the case they didn't have a common ancestor).

**2-** *int* type can't be used as *bool* type so `if (any_list.size == 0)` would work whereas `if (!any_list.size)` would throw an error

Thanks every one for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

`any_list` is a pointer, so you can't use the `.` operator. Try `any_list->size`.

Comment: well i tried this : ```Operator not supported for `int'
      if (!any_list->size)```

Comment: Also if i remove the pointer syntax (*) i got ```error: The name `size' does not exist in the context of `Gee.List?'
      if (!any_list->size)```

Comment: Yeah, you can't use `!` on integer. Try `any_list->size == 0`.